# Change normalized integer values to categories for classification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on this dataset with the following columns, N/A counts and example of a record:

```
  Serial No.           0
  GRE Score            0
  TOEFL Score          0
  University Rating    0
  SOP                  0
   LOR                  0
  CGPA                 0
 Research             0
 Chance of Admit      0
 dtype: int64
  0: 1 337 118 4 4.5 4.5 9.65 1 0.92
  1: 2 324 107 4 4.0 4.5 8.87 1 0.76
```

The column Chance of admit is a normalised intergar value ranging from 0 to 1, what i wanted to do was take this column and output a corrosponding ordered values where chance would be bins (low medium high) (unlikely doable likely) ect

What i have come across is that pandas has a built in function named to_categorical however, i don't understand it enough and what i read i still don't exactly get.

This dataset would be used for a decision tree where the labels would be the chance of admit

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, please inclued a sample of your data

Comment: @DanielMesejo 0: 1 337 118 4 4.5 4.5 9.65 1 0.92

Comment: I meant in your question

Comment: @DanielMesejo sorry yeah i added two records, i'm thinking there's no good way and just to implement a function to apply to the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to map a continuous variable to a categorical value based on ranges, for example:

```
0.96 -> high, 
0.31 -> low
...
```

So pandas provides with a function for just that, [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), from the documentation:

> Use cut when you need to segment and sort data values into bins. This
>   function is also useful for going from a continuous variable to a
>   categorical variable.

**Setup**

```
   Serial No.  GRE Score  TOEFL Score  ...  CGPA  Research  Chance of Admit
0           1        337          118  ...  9.65         1             0.92
1           2        324          107  ...  8.87         1             0.76
2           2        324          107  ...  8.87         1             0.31
3           2        324          107  ...  8.87         1             0.45

[4 rows x 9 columns]
```

Assuming the above setup, you could use `cut` like this:

```
labels = pd.cut(df['Chance of Admit'], [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0], labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])
print(labels)
```

**Output**

```
0      high
1      high
2       low
3    medium
Name: Chance of Admit, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [low < medium < high]
```

Notice that we are use 3 bins: `[(0, 0.33], (0.33, 0.66], (0.66, 1.0]]` and that the values of the column `Chance of Admit` are `[0.92, 0.76, 0.31, 0.45]`. If you want to change the label names just change the value of the labels parameter, for example: `labels=['unlikely', 'doable', 'likely']`. If you  need an ordinal value do:

```
labels = pd.cut(df['Chance of Admit'], [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0], labels=list(range(3)))
print(labels)
```

**Output**

```
0    2
1    2
2    0
3    1
Name: Chance of Admit, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 < 2]
```

Finally to put all in perspective you could do the following to add it to your DataFrame:

```
df['group'] = pd.cut(df['Chance of Admit'], [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0], labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Serial No.  GRE Score  TOEFL Score  ...  Research  Chance of Admit   group
0           1        337          118  ...         1             0.92    high
1           2        324          107  ...         1             0.76    high
2           2        324          107  ...         1             0.31     low
3           2        324          107  ...         1             0.45  medium

[4 rows x 10 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are "normalized" values...why would you need to categorize them? A simple threshould should work right?

i.e.
0-0.33 low
0.33-0.66 medium 
0.66-1.0 high

The only reason you would want to use an automated method would probably be if your number of categories keeps changing?

To do the category, you could use pandas to_categorical but you will need to determine the range and the number of bins (categories). From the docs this should work I think.

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(0, 100, 20)})

In [7]: labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 9) for i in range(0, 100, 10)]

In [8]: df['group'] = pd.cut(df.value, range(0, 105, 10), right=False, labels=labels)

In [9]: df.head(10)
Out[9]: 
   value    group
0     65  60 - 69
1     49  40 - 49
2     56  50 - 59
3     43  40 - 49
4     43  40 - 49
5     91  90 - 99
6     32  30 - 39
7     87  80 - 89
8     36  30 - 39
9      8    0 - 9
```

You can then replace df['group'] with your chance of admit column and fill up the necessary ranges for your discrete bins by threshold or automatic based on number of bins.

For your reference:

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Comment: @Jason.Chia this is exactly what i was looking for, i was right now just writing a custom python function where it uses if-else statements but i knew there was a better way thankk you so much